# Switching temperatures using a Bootstrap toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using an API that provides temperatures in both Celsius and Fahrenheit and trying to switch between the two using a toggle like so:

```js
//toggle temperature
var celc = $("#convert-temp").prop('checked');
var temp_c = 20; // dummy data
var temp_f = 60; // dummy data
if (celc == false) {
  $("#temp_c").html(temp_c + "<span>&#8451;</span>");
} else if (celc == true) {
  $("#temp_c").html(temp_f + "<span>&#8457;</span>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="convert-temp" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="&#8451;" data-off="&#8457;">Toggle Temperature</label>
</div>

<div id="temp_c"></div>
```

This toggle simply doesn't switch between the two temperatures. The variables temp_c and temp_f are being fetched from the API.

Answer (score 0):

I've just added some change to your code

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="convert-temp" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="&#8451;" data-off="&#8457;">Toggle Temperature</label>
</div>
<h1 id='temp_c'></h1>    

$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#convert-temp').click(function(){
        var temp_c = 51; will loaded from api
        var temp_f = 125
        var celc = $("#convert-temp").prop('checked');
                    if(celc === false){
                        $("#temp_c").html(temp_c+"<span>&#8451;</span>");
                    }else if(celc == true) {
                        $("#temp_c").html(temp_f+"<span>&#8457;</span>");
                    }
      })
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You may  try this code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="convert-temp" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="&#8451;" data-off="&#8457;">Toggle Temperature</label>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#convert-temp').on('click' , function(){
    var temp_c = 51; 
    var temp_f = 125
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("#temp_c").html(temp_f+"<span>&#8457;</span>");
    }else{
        $("#temp_c").html(temp_c+"<span>&#8451;</span>");

    }

  })
})
```

Comment: This didn't quite do it but thanks. Found a solution with the handler above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach a handler to the toggle checkbox and run your code when the value changes

```js
 var temp_c = 20; // dummy data
  var temp_f = 60; // dummy data

$('.checkbox').on('change','#convert-temp',function(){
  //toggle temperature
  var celc = $(this).prop('checked');
 
  if (celc == false) {
    $("#temp_c").html(temp_c + "<span>&#8451;</span>");
  } else if (celc == true) {
    $("#temp_c").html(temp_f + "<span>&#8457;</span>");
  }
});

// set the default:
$("#temp_c").html(temp_c + "<span>&#8451;</span>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="convert-temp" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="&#8451;" data-off="&#8457;">Toggle Temperature</label>
</div>

<div id="temp_c"></div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Missed out on the handler part. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to toggle by class instead of ID and use pure bootstrap IF you have the bootstrap css and js files in your page. Here is an example...

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label data-toggle="collapse"  data-parent="#temp" data-target=".temp_t"><input type="checkbox" id="convert-temp" >Toggle Temperature</label>
</div>

<div id="temp">
    <span id="temp_c" class="temp_t collapse in">&#8451;</span>
    <span id="temp_f" class="temp_t collapse">&#8457;</span>
</div>
```

I created a fiddle for it here ...
https://jsfiddle.net/oh07zekp/